# Rails returning 406 Not Acceptable for ajax request

Tags: ajax, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am completely stuck on this one and hours of searching hasn't turned up a result. I'm getting a 406 error when I try to do an ajax request. Here is my code..

Tiers controller

```
    def index
      series = Series.find_by_id(params[:series_id])
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => series.tiers }  
      end
    end
```

Javascript

```
    $('#series_id').change ->
      series_id = $('#series_id').val()

    $.get '/admin/tiers', {series_id:series_id}, (result) ->
      element = $('select[name *= "tier_id"]')
      element.empty()
      $.each result, (index, item) ->
        element.append $('<option/>', value:item.id, text: item.title)
```

And here is the error I am getting from the rails server

```
      Started GET "/admin/tiers/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-21 14:19:38 +1100
      Processing by Admin::TiersController#index as JSON
        Parameters: {"series_id"=>"1"}
        User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
          (0.1ms)  begin transaction
          (0.5ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_request_at" = '2013-01-21 14:19:38.827810', "perishable_token" = 'y0TMicsW2l4zgSiQcJx', "updated_at" = '2013-01-21 14:19:38.829452' WHERE "users"."id" = 1
          (2.5ms)  commit transaction
        Tier Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tiers".* FROM "tiers" WHERE "tiers"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
        Tier Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tiers".* FROM "tiers" 
        Series Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "series".* FROM "series" 
        Series Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "series".* FROM "series" WHERE "series"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
      Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 30ms (ActiveRecord: 4.4ms)
```

Really don't know what is stuffing it up, the controller looks fine and it looks like the content-type is json.

I'm also using rails 3.2.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you why that fixed the problem, but I think a better solution may be to use the [`.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) call rather than `.get`.

Rails generates a 406 when it can't find the proper response type for the requested type in the `Accept` header.  When I use [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) to snoop the request from a `.get`, I see the request header:

```
Accept: */*
```

This doesn't give Rails any information to work with.  If there's an extension on the requested URL, such as `.js` in the case of javascript, it can intuit from that as well, but that's not available for your JSON request.

When I make a `.getJSON` call, I see the request header:

```
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
```

This is probably enough information for Rails to match the requested type to your json handler.

Answer (score 3):

So changing

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => series.tiers }  
  end
```

to

```
 render :json => series.tiers
```

fix the problem but I am still not sure why :( If anyone has any idea why your input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The reason why is because you are no longer responding to a specifically requested format. You're ignoring any requested format, and rendering JSON output no matter what.

Typically, the format in Rails is decided by appending the format as an extension to the URL. If you were to call that same URL with .json on the end of the path, it would also work.